# IDEs to organize #include's in C++?

Tags: c++, ide, include

I recently discovered the nice `Ctrl+Shift+O` command in Eclipse to organize import's.
Is there an IDE with that feature, for #include's in a C++ program?

Comment: huh?  You can run eclipse on Ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt`.  Not sure what your question is?

Comment: @Tom: That was my first thought too. But I think the OP is asking how to get the Java feature of organizing imports with C++ #include lines. I found a forum question on it: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/34120/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse CDT 8.2 (Kepler), which was just released, can do this now: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn82#Organize_Includes_Command

Answer (score 4):

`#include` have not the same meaning than java's `import`. It's basically a copy/paste instruction inside the compiled file.

So, the IDE can't move the `#include` without changing the semantic of the code where it was put first.

Don't get me wrong : in most code, order of inclusion have no impact if all the includes are done at the start of the file, but that's because developers make sure it is.

The language just don't allow to do this in a safe way.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse CDT has `Ctrl+Shift+N` shortcut for **Add Include** command, if this is what you are asking for. Look Eclipse Help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_m_edit.htm).

Comment: Adding and organizing are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

[codelite IDE](http://www.codelite.org) offers similar functionalities to those of eclipse:

Ctrl-Shift-O -> show a layout of the current file (similar to eclipses Ctrl-O i believe)

Ctrl-Shift-R -> Open a resource in the workspace

Ctrl-Shift-T -> Open a type (class / namespace / typedef etc)

You can also right click on any class and it will automatically add include files for the clicked type (e.g. right clicking on 'string', you will be suggested with #include )